# Jquery td to text field issue

Tags: jquery

I am doing on some table with few rows so when click on td that should be change with text fields for all rows along with same value in `td` when some updates has been done after update those should be revert to same non edit position with updated values.

pls suggest any solution for this

http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".g1").click(function () {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' value='");
        parent.children(":text").focus();
        return false;
    });
    $(".g1 :text").live("blur", function () {
        $(this).replaceWith(this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: There's a reason SO won't let you post a link to jsfiddle without posting some code, please don't try to get around it. Post your code here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what youre trying to attain

Comment: You're missing the closing quote and `>` in `<input type='text' value='`.

Comment: should be : `<input type='text' value=''>`

Answer (score 3):

First change the html and remove the inputs as they'll be added at the run time

```
<table>
  <tr>
<td class="g1">some text
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="g2">some text
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="g3">some text
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then change the script as :

```
$(document).ready (function() {

 $("td").click (function() {
  $(this).html("<input type='text' class='editText' value='"+$(this).text()+"' />");
  $(this).children(":text").focus();
  return false;
 });
 $("table").on("blur","td input:text", function() {
  $(this).replaceWith ($(this).val());
 });
});
```

and finally, remove the css of the inputs :

```
td.edit input { display: block; }

tr td{border:1px #000 solid; background-color:lightblue; padding:3px; 
}
```

I am not quite sure what you want but here's the demo : 
http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/6/

Comment: Hi,

how could i do for a entire rows like if i have 11 rows in three portions in middle entire portion i need to edit in one click how could it do. pls look this http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/8/

Comment: You want to edit the whole row at a time, I mean with 3 input boxes active simultaneously?

Comment: pls look this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/12/ i want to edit at a time all middle rows at one click and when my edit was done that should be readable format once i click on update button

Comment: I worked on your previous requirement but somehow I got stuck at focussing out of the table. You can view here : http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/15/ See if you figure out the problem

Comment: And if you want an update button, this might help both of us :)
http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/17/

Comment: it looks fine but i want to editable only middle entire rows which is having all rows 123 values. also can we use a button after editing done for updating the values

Comment: looks good to see the output but can you make it the all middle rows should be editable which is all 123 values tds

Comment: do you have any idea how to show the bar progress based on live entering values

Comment: Hi when i change input:text to input:number getting a issue can you check once

Comment: :number is an invalid pseudo selector. For that you need to write input[type='number']. see http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/19/ also you need to change the type of the input added to 'number'.

What kind of progress bar are you talking about. Can you please show a demo site where that is implemented.

Comment: Hi thanks, and one more thing i can say in middle rows user no need to enter any letters "abcd" only numbers"123".

and also you asked some ref example pls have a look the following one which is in angular UI

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Actually my requirement is every row having their own progress bar on right side of the ending row, when user entering some value in middle row progress has to show the based on the value.

Comment: Hi just look this my working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ckNSZ/19/ Concept is when i enter some value in any mid row the progress bar should be related to show by animate as per previous ref url.

like this every row have their own progress bar based on values static also would be show as per values basically percentage round to be overall upto 20%

Answer (score 1):

Try it
html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="g1 can_edit">some text can edit
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="g2">some text
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="g3 can_edit">some text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $(".can_edit").click(function(){
        if($(this).find("input").length==0){
            var currentText = $(this).text();
            $(this).html("<input id='tamp_input' type='text' class='edit' value='"+currentText+"' />");
            $("#tamp_input").blur(function(){
                $(this).parent().html($(this).val());
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/haduythuan/8x4qp/4/

Comment: Hi in your code text value is hiding when input comes but is should keep the text same and convert into inputfield with value.

and also i have around 3 rows so when click on any row all should be convert as input text fields in one action

Comment: I have used like the same but not working properly because i want edit all middle portion rows at one click pls check this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/12/

Comment: almost reached but i want entire middle rows should be editable when one click on any middle row. after click on update button that should be back to readable mode.

Comment: That you need. http://jsfiddle.net/haduythuan/8x4qp/16/
I hope i not misunderstand again :)

Comment: i want to enter only numbers in all middle rows not letters how can we do it that when letter entering that filed is not valid

Comment: Many thanks! is there any way to convert code to angularjs my working fiddle is here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ckNSZ/19/
when i am entered some value on mid rows the progress bar should show based on values percentage would be upto 20% is heigh

Comment: I am not understand what you want.

Comment: basically when entering some value on middle row based on that live progress bar will be generate.

just look this url how they done based on value showing 
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you out

```
$(".g1").click (function() {
   var pdata = $(this).children("p").text();
   $(this).children("input").show().val(pdata);
   $(this).children("p").hide();
   $(this).children(":text").focus();
});

$("input[type='text']").on("blur", function() {
   $(this).hide();
   $(this).siblings("p").show();    
   $(this).siblings("p").text($(this).val());
});
```

Demo link : http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/11/

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. When you use `replaceWith`, you're replacing the entire `g1` TD, not just the text. So you were creating an invalid DOM, with an `input` directly within a `tr`. The other result of this is that there's no longer a `g1` element, so the selector `g1 :text` that you bound the `blur` handler to didn't exist; so nothing fired when you finished editing the element.

Change the HTML to:

```
<tr>
    <td class="g1"><span>some text</span>
        <input type="text" class="edit" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

This adds a separate `span` element to contain the text.

add the following CSS:

```
td.edit span {
    display: none;
}
```

so the span will be hidden while you're editing the text.

and change the JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".g1 span").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('edit');
        $(this).siblings(":text").focus();
        return false;
    });
    $(".g1 :text").blur(function () {
        $(this).siblings("span").text($(this).val());
        $(this).parent().removeClass('edit');
    });
});
```

This just toggles the `edit` class, rather than replacing elements.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8x4qp/2/)

Comment: Hi,

how could i do for a entire rows like if i have 11 rows in three portions in middle entire portion i need to edit in one click how could it do. pls look this http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/8/

Comment: Give them all a class, like the `can_edit` class in HDT's answer, and use that in the above code.

Comment: not working some times that code when this scenario " when click on one by one all middle rows it wont working properly pls check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8x4qp/12/

even though i would like to click all middle rows at one time

Comment: Your fiddle is nothing like my answer.